# Elasticsearch how to take advantage of cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

After changing single-node to multi-node cluster, do you have to take any action to take advantage of cluster?

For instance, our application server uses single `ip/port` (our single-node's ip/port) to search documents.
In addition, logstash, kibana, spark, they all point to the single ip/port.

Should I put a `load balancer` to take advantage of the multi node? or do I get something for free maybe?

I followed the following docker file (just **changed network-mode to host and deployed on multiple hosts**)

```
  es-log-00:
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: ./compose/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
     args:
       - VERSION=${VERSION}
       - ELASTICSEARCH_NETWORK_HOST=${ELASTICSEARCH_NETWORK_HOST}
       - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
       - MEM=${MEM}
       - ENV=${ENV}
   container_name: es-log-00
   network_mode: host
   environment:
       - node.name=node-master
       - discovery.seed_hosts=node1,node2
       - cluster.initial_master_nodes=node-master,node1,node2
       - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
       - cluster.name=littlehome-log
       - network.publish_host=192.168.1.105
   volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - /var/lib/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    - /var/lib/elasticsearch-backup:/var/lib/elasticsearch-backup
   ulimits:
     memlock:
       soft: -1
       hard: -1
     nofile:
       soft: 65536
       hard: 65536

   es-log-01:
   restart: always
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: ./compose/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
     args:
       - VERSION=${VERSION}
       - ELASTICSEARCH_NETWORK_HOST=${ELASTICSEARCH_NETWORK_HOST}
       - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_SEARCH}
       - MEM=${MEM1}
       - ENV=${ENV}
   container_name: es-log-01
   network_mode: host
   environment:
       - node.name=node1
       - discovery.seed_hosts=node-master,node2
       - cluster.initial_master_nodes=node-master,node1,node2
       - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
       - cluster.name=littlehome-log
       - network.publish_host=192.168.1.123
   volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - data-log1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
   ulimits:
     memlock:
       soft: -1
       hard: -1
     nofile:
       soft: 65536
       hard: 65536
```

Comment: Makes no sense put a cluster on same machine. They will share resources. The only advantage you can take is from disk IO if each node use a separate disk. Otherwise, it will probably be slower.

Comment: Unless you have more then 64GB of ram, it will have no advantage.

Comment: See this post on elasticsearch forum: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-i-run-multiple-elasticsearch-nodes-on-the-same-machine/67

Comment: I'm running 3 ES on 3 hosts, I think you are assuming I'm running 3 ES on 1 host?

Comment: Due to your docker-compose file, I'm assuming that you are running on same machine (physically, not virtually)

Comment: I should have stressed that more.. I edited the op to make it bold;;

Comment: Why are you limiting your memory to 512mb on each node?

Comment: Sorry I confused you much, I thought putting my actual docker-compose would be more confusing. but it seems putting example composer was more confusing.. :( I put my compose file in the op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to take advantage of parallelization in Elasticsearch. When you have an index with multiple shards in a cluster, Elasticsearch will attempt to balance the primary shards for each index across the cluster, and when you make a query, it will send the query to the node holding the primary replica for each shard. Each node will then execute the query against that shard and return results to a coordinating node, which performs any ordering or aggregations and returns the resultset back to the client.

Using a load balancer is a good idea in case an individual node goes down, but in general you don't have to do anything except to have multiple shards per index.

Comment: I see many ES related client (such as elasticsearch-py, spark) allows you set [host1, host2] for ES host. I wonder if giving more hosts to these es-clients have benefits?

Comment: Elasticsearch clients use multiple hosts for cluster topology discovery. Clients will try hosts until a live one is found, and then interrogate that host for the current cluster topology. This is good for ensuring resilient client access to clusters, but doesn't have any performance implications.